# How i can Load Csv file into Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, csv

I have my csv file in /tmp directory below is the permissions of csv file......
**-rwxr-xr-x 1 user    user    22896 Feb 25 11:19 ex.csv**

**THis is my query**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '~/tmp/ex.csv' INTO TABLE csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**THis is the Error**

```
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/home/user/tmp/ex.csv' (Errcode: 2)
```

Anyone Could you please resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error. I use phpmyadmin and import csv file from gui.

Try:-http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Answer (score 0):

From a [forum post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?51,16818,16835#msg-16835):

> MySQL either couldn't see or couldn't access the directory & files.
>   After I copied the relevant files (for the catalog there are actually
>   several) into a subdirectory of MySQL, it loaded ok.

Try that and let me know if it works out for you.